# Constructing an aggregate CMake project

Tags: c++, cmake

I want to make a CMake project that aggregates two other CMake projects that are dependent on each other.

```
prj/CMakeLists.txt
prj/sub_prj0/CMakeLists.txt
prj/sub_prj1/CMakeLists.txt
```

I tried:

```
add_subdirectory(sub_prj0)
add_subdirectory(sub_prj1)
```

The problem with this, is that sub_prj1 uses `find_package(sub_prj0)`. It will look for sub_prj0 targets in the system. It doesn't know that sub_prj0 is being built in the same parent project.

What's the right way to go about this?

`ExternalProject_Add`?

Comment: `set(sub_prj0_FOUND 1)` and set the stuff that `find_package` would have set before `add_subdirectory(sub_prj1)`

Comment: I’m making progress by skipping the find_package in sub_prj1 when it detects that CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME != PROJECT_NAME. Luckily since I can control the CMakeLists in all projects this should work for me.